# Resetting component variables when a component is made active

Tags: angular

I have a component that takes the user's URL and then grabs some files based on that URL. Based on those files, I then create some variables by appending file names to each other. My issue is that each time the component is shown, the data from the previous time that the component was shown is still present.

For example, if the app launches with the variable set to and empty string and the text appended to it is '/new/file', I can navigate to another component and then come back to that same url and that variable will be '/new/file/new/file' as the previous data was retained and the actions performed again.

I was under the impression that the ngOnInit was performed each time that the component was loaded. That does not seem to be the case as the variables are not reset. What lifecycle hook or other method can be used to reset variables each time that the component is made active?

```
ngOnInit(): void {


    this.filePath = ''; // does not reset the variable to an empty string when component is active
    this.heirarchy = []; // does not reset the array each time the component is made active
```

Answer (score 0):

You use ngOnChanges for that [link](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) But the fact that it's not reset means that the component did not get destroyed.

Comment: I though that the component got destroyed when you navigated away to another component?

Comment: Yeah that should be the case but I don't know how your project is structured, do you navigate to different routes etc.